# Location header with relative path not re-directing

Tags: php

My header tag doesn't redirect correctly and I don't find out why. This is my line:

```
header('Location:../destination.php');
```

The file is located at: `www.example.com/one/two/example.php`

Now, if I enter the page and get instantly redirected (as it should) it loads  `www.example.com/one/two/example/destination.php` instead of `www.example.com/one/destination.php`.

It just adds the destination.php to the current path. Very strange.

Comment: Is destination.php in folder named `one` ?

Comment: I'd guess you'd need to give it the entire path, I went through this when I was making my site from `v1 -> v2`, you'd just have to do `header('Location: /where/you/want/to/go/index.php')`, could be wrong. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
header("Location: //www.example.com/one/destination.php");
```

I used a scheme-less URI because the question doesn't specify whether you're using `http://` or `https://`.

Although relative paths are acceptable, the spec calls for the use of absolute URIs. I would rely on that for consistency.

> [**14.30
>   Location**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)
>
> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient
>   to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request
>   or identification of a new resource.
>
> The field value consists of a single absolute URI.
>
> ```
>    Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```

Comment: Scheme-less URLs are also good for possibly used https calls to JS/CSS files from Google/jQuery scripts etc. while being in an https site/environment.

Comment: Quick suggestion: adding `exit;` after header which will prevent further execution should there be more code below what they're using or might use in the future, as per what the manual suggests http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php